# How Provide transaction In Magento?

Tags: magento-1.8, transaction, ce-1.9.0.1

When you save your multiple Model Object object then I want to provide Transaction. How can I achieve in magento?

Any one Please Guide Me?

Comment: what do you mean by `multiple Model Object`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I hope I understood correctly your question.
If you want to save X objects at once and roll back all of them in case something goes wrong try this.

```
$transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');
$transaction->addObject($obj1);
$transaction->addObject($obj2);
...
$transaction->addObject($objX);

$transaction->save();
```

This will call `->save()` for each object you added using `addObject` but everything will be done inside a transaction.

Comment: Hi @Marius, I want to get id of $obj1 before addObject $obj2. How to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look e.g. into `\Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::saveAttribute`

```
public function saveAttribute(Varien_Object $object, $attributeCode)
{
    // ...
    $adapter        = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
    // ...
    $adapter->beginTransaction();

    try {
        // ...
        $adapter->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $adapter->rollback();
        throw $e;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I have 3 Model Object like product, order and custom table then this will work?

Comment: mysql transactions work for select/update/delete. As long as you don't create tables, this work. You should start the transaction before the first save and commit it after the last save - somehow.