# Magento 2 - How to provide transaction?

Tags: magento2, transaction

In magento 2, How to provide transaction ?
Anyone knew, please show me step by step.
I found a solution for M1.x here [How Provide transaction In Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14849/how-provide-transaction-in-magento)

Comment: Please explain your question further. What kind of transaction? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 9):

I resolved my issue. below:

```
<?php
namespace Odoo\Office\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
/**
* 
*/
class DbConnection
{
    /** 
     * Define common connection
     * @var unknown
     */
    protected $_resource;
    protected $_dbConnection;

    protected function __construct(
        ResourceConnection $resource,
        )
    {
        # code...
        // Set common connection
        $this->_resource        = $resource;
        $this->_dbConnection    = $this->_resource->getConnection();
    }

    public function Trans(){
        try{
            // Start transaction
            $this->_dbConnection->beginTransaction(); 

            //........

            // Commit transaction
            $this->_dbConnection->commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Rollback transaction
            $this->_dbConnection->rollBack();
        } 
    }

}
```